# Angular 2/4/5: how to move element within another element

Tags: javascript, css, angular

In my Angular project, I am playing with CSS to move the image/video element inside a "stage" element.

What I have so far:

**SCSS:**

```
.stage {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: coral
}

video {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="stage">
  <video controls autoplay [ngStyle]="{'top': top, 'left': left">
    <source src="http://www.archive.org/download/AnimatedMechanicalArtPiecesAtMit/P1120973_512kb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-1 ">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-tn " (click)="moveLeft()">
      Left
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-tn " (click)="moveRight()">
      Right
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-tn " (click)="moveUp()">
      Up
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-tn " (click)="moveDown()">
      Down
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CODE:**

```
l: number = 0;
t: number = 0;
left = '0px';
top = '0px';

moveUp() {
  this.t -= 5;
  this.top = this.t + 'px';
}

moveDown() {

  this.t += 5;
  this.top = this.t + 'px';

}

moveLeft() {
  this.l -= 5;
  this.left = this.l + 'px';
}

moveRight() {
  this.l += 5;
  this.left = this.l + 'px';
}
```

Result: Image/video moved and left blank space.

[image]

My question: how to keep image/video remain within the stage when moving left, right, up, down

For example, The image (blue) will be held when the image reaches to the top and left edge of stage (yellow).

[image]

Hope my explanation is clear. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Your example video element is larger than the stage, so you won't be able to keep the whole video within the stage. Can you elaborate on how the video is allowed to move within the stage?

Comment: Yes, video element larger than the stage is for purpose: to demonstrate the idea of focusing on different areas of video. Only area of video in stage will be displayed, the remained part of video (out of the stage) is hidden (refer to the scss for more detail).